# When I go to login page it is in desktop mode (responsive design disappear)

Tags: css, responsive, html-templates

everyone! I am working on a project that is based on [this](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/vanno-consumers-reviews-and-rating-directory/full_screen_preview/22805107) template. Everything is OK on the template except for the login page. The problem there is that when someone opens the site over the phone, the page comes out like on a desktop. I opened the original template's login page from themeforest and saw that it is actually responsive, but not for me. Where can the problem lie? Unfortunately, I can't share a link to my project, as it is for a customer.

To view the login page that I'm using - click on **Pages** and then **Login**

Comment: I can really only speculate with this information base. Is it reproducible with your phone on the linked website?

Comment: Yes, when I open the login page in themeforest from my phone it is responsive but not in my project.

Comment: Did you set the viewport meta tag in your html head? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` 
The actual resolution of the phone may be larger than what is set in the mediaquery, therefore mediaqueries may not work with the mobile device (mediaquery is set to lower than 991px width, but phone has actually 1920px. The viewport meta tag is used to compensate for that.

Comment: Adding this meta tag did the work. Gosh, thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Perfect, i'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are missing the viewport meta tag in your html head.
The viewport meta tag is needed to control the dimensions and scaling of the web page. In your case the display of your login is controlled by media queries, e.g. `max-width: 920px`. The phones actual resolution is probably higher than that. By adding `width=device-width` you essentially tell the browser on the phone to scale the page down to the actual screen size, and not use the resolution for the media queries.

It is worth noting that you can add more settings to your viewport meta tag, e.g. to control zoom (you can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- other header stuff -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <!-- document body -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

insert this into head tag

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0,viewport-fit=cover">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this HTML Viewport to you `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```